# Gestionar peticiones hacia consultas en SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en php que se comunica con un programa y con ese programa se puede agregar, editar y eliminar usuarios.

La aplicación también eliminar,agregar y editar usuarios, las dos se sincronizan por medio de un trigger el problema es que se estaría produciendo un bucle. Quiero saber si existe alguna sentencia o función en SQL Server donde pueda gestionar esas peticiones.

Comment: A qué te refieres con bucle? El Trigger se ejecuta una vez por cada acción.

Comment: Claro,por ejemplo en una edicion no termina nunca de hacerlo ya que de las dos partes se ejecutan trigger por un lado y hooks por el otro..